# Bank statement splitting

Tags: excel, vba, bank

[Base Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Npoze.jpg)[Output required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxMt9.jpg)I have a bank statement with multiple accounts rolled into one excel sheet.

I need to break the sheet into multiple sheets based on the account number.

The columns are something like this (commas indicating change in column)-

Bank Name, xxx

Customer Number, xxx

Branch Name, xxx

Account Number, xxx

Entry Date, Value Date, Customer Reference, Bank Reference, Transaction, Description,   By Order Of / Beneficiary,  Transaction Amount

and then again continuing with the next bank account -

Bank Name, xxx

Customer Number, xxx

Branch Name, xxx

Account Number, xxx

Is there a possibility of splitting the data? I was able to code only for a single account. not multiple ones.

Comment: Show us the code for the single account...

Comment: update the screenshot of your sheet as well as the code you wrote so far? What did you use to get that output? formula or scripts?

Comment: added screenshot of base data and output desired